# JavaFX Text constructor vs. relocate

Tags: text, javafx-2

In a custom JavaFX UI Control, I want to place some text in the corners of the Control. Here is the source code from my Skin class:

```
double width = control.getWidth();
double height = control.getHeight();

Text test1Text = new Text(0, 0, "top left");
Text test2Text = new Text(0, height-1, "bottom left");
Text test3Text = new Text("top right");
test3Text.relocate(width - test3Text.getLayoutBounds().getWidth(), 0);
Text test4Text = new Text("bottom right");
test4Text.relocate(width - test4Text.getLayoutBounds().getWidth(), height-1);
```

Unfortunately, it seems to make a difference, whether I construct a text at a given co-ordinate or whether I construct it without co-ordinates and relocate it in place afterwards:

- In the first case, the co-ordinate in the constructor will be the bottom-left co-ordinate of the text.
- In the second case, the given co-ordinate will be the top-left co-ordinate.

Any ideas for this strange behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Text` is being drawn from (0,0) position to the right and up. E.g. if you create `new Text("Hello")` and ask for it bounds you will see that they have negative vertical coordinates `[minX:0.0, minY:-12.94921875]`

The reason IMHO is next: `Text` is being drawn in Controls and they care more about baseline of the text. Imagine 2 buttons with text "water" and "Water" -- you would really expect them to be aligned by the baseline rather then top-left corner:

[image]

`relocate()` method from the other side works with a regular `Node`s and operates layout which always calculated for top-left corner.

Comment: That sounds reasonable. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Additional remark: in fact, one can set the origin of the text coordinate system via setTextOrigin: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/text/Text.html#setTextOrigin%28javafx.geometry.VPos%29
You can decide yourself whether you prefer coordinates relative to top left, bottom left, center left or baseline left of the text.

Comment: Perhaps `relocate()` plus `getBaselineOffset()` would do the trick? e.g. `text.relocate(someX, someY - text.getBaselineOffset()`

Answer (score 1):

Since JavaFX has been open sourced for the most of its parts, here is the codes for both (JavaFX 8)
[javafx.scene.text.Text](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/raw-file/eb8fe386f751/javafx-ui-common/src/javafx/scene/text/Text.java) and [javafx.scene.Node](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/raw-file/5badf4a1d5b3/javafx-ui-common/src/javafx/scene/Node.java).
I could not examine in depth but it is obvious that the `Text constructor` and `Node#relocate()` are doing different things:
Text constructor

```
public Text(double x, double y, String text) {
    this(text);
    setX(x);
    setY(y);
}
```

Node#relocate()

```
public void relocate(double x, double y) {
        setLayoutX(x - getLayoutBounds().getMinX());
        setLayoutY(y - getLayoutBounds().getMinY());

        PlatformLogger logger = Logging.getLayoutLogger();
        if (logger.isLoggable(PlatformLogger.FINER)) {
            logger.finer(this.toString()+" moved to ("+x+","+y+")");
        }
}
```

That's all for my idea, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the source code! I hope that whole situation will improve with Java 8...